# Relatively slow page load in my profile page

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, wcf, optimization

It takes an average of 4.5 seconds to load a profile page in our site.
We've turned on developer dashboard and we narrowed down what was causing this.
We have around 7 calls that look like this:
**`ExecuteWcfOperation:http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetUserData 267.98ms`**

I know it's very vague, but what would be possible causes as to why it would take this long?
In our Dev environment, it only takes an average of `11ms` and a max of around `70ms`.

If it helps, here's the landscape of this environment:
- 2 web front ends
- 2 app servers
- 1 DB server

Answer (score 2):

There is no proper answer for this question rather you just make sure that all performance tuning things performed.

I would do / check couple of things.

- Make sure SQL server memory usage is fine
- auto-growth rate for Profile DBs and MySie DBs should be MSFT best recomendation i.e 256MB
- Check Antivirus
- App Pool of MySite & also User Profile Service
- Perform IIS reset on all servers in farm
- Stop and start User Profile services
- Dis associate Profile services proxy to Mysite and re associate it.

http://tristanwatkins.com/user-profile-service-connection-slow-first-page-load/
http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/10-reasons-why-sharepoint-performance-can-slow

Answer (score 1):

Deactivating the SharePoint Publishing web feature and check .

Comment: could you paste entire developer dashboard result .

Comment: [Here you go](http://imgur.com/3Ecf7Hk,QjOjMoD#0). There are two results.

Comment: its not taking 4.5 sec though .

Answer (score 1):

Have you ruled out the network? I see this very often with bad Network Load Balancing. Use a HOSTS file to pin the IP Address of one server and test again.

Comment: Hmmm.. good point! This definitely makes sense as well.